# Squarespace site - some images not responsive

Tags: css, image, mobile

A website of a friend that was designed on Squarespace is located at www.diamondathome.com.

The site itself is mobile responsive, but the Facebook and Linkedin icons at the top of the homepage are not scaling and appear too large on mobile browsers.

I've tried many tweaks by adding custom CSS and nothing is working.

Can anyone give me some ideas on what the heck is going on?

Thanks!

Scott.

Comment: Their `width` and `height` are dynamically inserted? As I tested here, in 320px they became with 129px, both.

Answer (score 0):

This will sort of fix it:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
.sqs-gallery-design-grid-slide {
width: 40px !important;}

img.thumb-image.loaded {
width: 20px !important;
height: 20px !important;
}
}
```

If you have access to the CSS file in Squarespace you will find this on site.css . Else you can add this to another css file.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code. That worked but it moved the images over to the left instead of being centered.  Is there anyway I can center those social media logos on the mobile site?